# add vertical list of links on left side of template Joomla 4

Tags: joomla, joomla4

in the Cassiopeia template, a vertical list of links on the left side (left middle). I am new in Joomla, so I looked how to modify a template and I found it is in Joomla webiste, but I think I have the option also in the server (iPage).

What I found was a bit confusing for me, and now I am completely lost.

Can anyone give me some guidance on what is the best way to make changes, and how to make the change I need?

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.